# Very many "fetch timed out" errors in apache log

Tags: apache2, mod-pagespeed

I've installed `mod_pagespeed` with the config included below. While it works well, I am getting a lot of output in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file that I'm not sure how to resolve.

**Config**

```
ModPagespeed on
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/var/mod_pagespeed/cache/"
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,rewrite_css,inline_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript,rewrite_javascript,inline_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
ModPagespeedRateLimitBackgroundFetches on
```

**Errors**

```
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [error] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Serf status 120105(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 30 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [error] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Serf status 120105(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 30 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [error] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Serf status 120105(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 30 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [warn] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Fetch timed out: http://IP_ADDRESS:443/img/icon/arrow-right-5x8.png (30) waiting for 50 ms
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [warn] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Fetch timed out: http://IP_ADDRESS:443/img/layout/navbar-divider.png (29) waiting for 50 ms
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [warn] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Fetch timed out: http://IP_ADDRESS:443/img/layout/navbar-label.png (28) waiting for 50 ms
[Fri Jun 28 13:29:15 2013] [warn] [mod_pagespeed 1.4.26.3-3101 @31464] Fetch timed out: http://IP_ADDRESS:443/img/layout/portal-icon.png (27) waiting for 50 ms
```

Answer (score 9):

By default, mod_pagespeed will fetch css/js/images using http. If the webserver doesn't respond within 50ms (by default), it will abort the request, and log the timeout messages you are seeing.

However, there seems to be another problem: Serf status 120105 indicates a bad response was received. You might want to investigate the apache logs, maybe you can find a clue about what is going on. I don't think those messages are related to mod_pagespeed, it is just the messenger in this case.

To get rid of these messages, I suggest you configure pagespeed to load files from disk instead[1] using **ModPagespeedLoadFromFile** and friends, which will resolve these messages, and brings these other benefits:

- It will probably be a lot faster
- It consumes less webserver resources by avoiding loopback requests
- Changes to css/js/images will be processed immediately

[1] https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains